Cannot build IOS app due to CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"
When attempting to build the Flutter app on an "Apple MAC M1," I encountered an error. I attempted to resolve it by executing the following command:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -rf Podfile.lock && flutter build ios && arch -x86_64 pod install

The error was related to CocoaPods not finding compatible versions for the pod "Firebase/CoreOnly." Specifically, the versions identified were:
In the Podfile.lock snapshot:

Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.20.0)

In the Podfile:

firebase_core (from .symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios) was resolved to 3.1.0, which requires Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.27.0)

Detailed error

      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.16.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.27.0/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.20.0)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.27.0)


    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
       You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install

Due to the lack of a macOS machine, I used "Codemagic" for building and publishing the app.
I tried resolving this by browsing several articles on Stack Overflow, but they were somewhat outdated and didn't help me. That's why I'm asking this.
I attempted to update all Firebase packages, but the issue persisted. I also experimented with various Flutter versions like "3.19.0," "3.22.0," "3.22.2," and "3.23.0-0.1-pre," along with different CocoaPods versions like "1.15.2" and "1.15.0," but unfortunately, no solution was found.

did you try to run pod repo update command before flutter build as the error message suggests?
